# AndroidStudio retrofit2 response getting data

Tags: java, android-studio, retrofit2

My REST API response looks like this:

```
{
"message": "OK",
"data": {
    "api_token": "1dwdafg45567fsf",
    "name": "Albert",
    "second_name": "Ferbs"
 }
}
```

My Interface is:

```
@POST("api/login")
Call<LoginResponse> loginUser(@Body LoginRequest loginRequest);
```

I want to get a value from "api_token".
My LoginResponse is:

```
public class LoginResponse implements Serializable {
private String api_token;

public String getApi_token() {
    return api_token;
}

public void setApi_token(String api_token) {
    this.api_token= api_token;
}
}
```

But *loginResponse.getApi_token()* returns me "null". What should i do?

Comment: There seems to be a missing link. How do you parse the `JSON` returned by your API in the `LoginResponse`? Unless this is done, `api_token` is not initialized (`null`).

Comment: Well, for example, if i will ask for getData, where Data is an object, i will recieve smth like: api_token=dawdawdawdaw,name=name,second_name=secon_name. I just want to know how to get only api token/name/second_name from this. So i dont know how to parse it

Comment: Have a look e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android

Comment: Got nothing working here. I think that Retrofit should have its own methods for parsing and answer(

Comment: Yes, see e.g. here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/json-parsing-in-android-using-retrofit-library/
Please add more information of what was not working, otherwise we are nto bale to help here.

Comment: Just got nothing after using JSONArray or JSONObject. I think that my problem is in Interface or in LoginResponse. Mb i have to add a class Data, or set Call<LoginResponse> as  list?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230974/discussion-between-beliy-and-johannes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do as below:

first create Data class parser

```
public class Data implements Serializable {
       @SerializedName("api_token")
       private String api_token;

       public String getApi_token() {
       return api_token;
      }

}
```

then change your loginResponse class :

```
public class LoginResponse implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("message")
private String message;
@SerializedName("data")
private Data data;

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
}
```

}

then you can call your method

```
response.getData().getApi_token();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved my problem! You are my hero